# Call Function To Send Email Without So Much Code In Excel

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that select pre-defined cells and from this creates and email when a user presses a button. This worked fine when I had about 3 to 4 rows of data but now I have over 500 rows.

What I would like to do is instead of duplicating the code for each row is have one function that gets called on each time. I want the code to work out the row from a link at the end of the Row (which I also need to figure out how to link to the VBA, I know how to do it via a button but a link at the end of each row would be much better). The Link will say send email. If the user presses this link, then it will select the row the link is on and send the email. Hope that makes sense. I just wanted 1 function this could be called from. Instead of having to duplicate the code each time for each row.

Any good ways of doing this? Please see my code and spreadsheet below.

```
Sub SendEmail()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    objEmail.Subject = Cells(2, 1).Text
    objEmail.Body = "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(2, 3).Text & vbNewLine & "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(2, 6).Text
    objEmail.To = Cells(2, 5).Text
    objEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "test@test.com"
objEmail.Display
End Sub
```

I have also attached an example of my spreadsheet. Please note the full on spreadsheet has over 500 records. This is a much condensed version:

[>> LINK to sample workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8OtUevU1V5sfkhMaGpLd2VWaHhjVlBmS1Jna2dnekVMREZmVWpPT3h6RmxHRGFRQ3RHYTQ)

Comment: LOL so many answers missing the point. Your first challenge is finding the row that you clicked. I messed around and put this code into VBA: `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    MsgBox (Target.Address)
End Sub` Can you try it in your project and confirm that it shows something that can be used to uniquely identify the row you clicked?

Comment: I managed to get it working with help below and I also did a bit of trial and error. In the end my code now looks like this: Via the workbook: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8OtUevU1V5sVkdndDd2UldxMHM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try below:

```
Sub SendEmail(r As Range)
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With objEmail
        .Subject = r.Value2
        .Body = "============" & vbNewLine & r.Offset(0, 2).Value2 & vbNewLine & _
                "============" & vbNewLine & r.Offset(0, 5).Value2
        .To = r.Offset(0, 4).Value2
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "test@test.com"
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Then test it:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lr As Long, cel As Range
    With Sheets("SheetName")
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr = 1 Then Msgbox "No email to send": Exit Sub
        For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & lr)
            SendEmail cel
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit:** To send mail when hyperlink is pressed, you can use a worksheet event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo halt
    If Target.Name = "Send Mail" Then '<~~ Check which hyperlink is pressed
        '*** This will call the SendEmail routine above and pass
        '*** the range where the hyperlink is on
        '*** Take note of the Offset(0, -5). I just based it on your screen shot
        '*** where your subject is 5 cells from the cell with Send mail
        '*** Adjust it to your actual target range
        Application.Run SendEmail, Target.Range.Offset(0, -5)
        'SendEmail Target.Range.Offset(0, -5)
    End If
moveon:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume moveon
End Sub
```

I used `Application.Run` so that you don't have to worry whether your `SendEmail` sub routine is *Public* or not. If you decide to just make it *Public* in a *Module*, you can use the commented line.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. I re edited what I said above as I dont believe it read correctly. I want the code to work out the row from a link at the end of the Row. The Link will say send email. If the user presses this link then it will select the row the link is on and send the email. Hope that makes sense. I just wanted 1 function this could be called from. Instead of having to duplicate the code.. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the Trick L42. Works a treat. You rock :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the row from the selection.   Select your row, then get the row from the selected range, and use it in your code for the cells(iRow, 1)

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
Dim SelRange As Range
Dim iRow As Integer

Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
Set SelRange = Selection

iRow = SelRange.Row

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   objEmail.Subject = Cells(iRow , 1).Text
    objEmail.Body = "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(iRow , 3).Text & vbNewLine & "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(iRow , 6).Text
    objEmail.To = Cells(iRow , 5).Text
    objEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "test@test.com"
objEmail.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Matt,Sorry I kind of explained wrong what I wanted to do above. I want the code to work out the row from a link at the end of the Row. The Link will say send email. If the user presses this link then it will select the row the link is on and send the email. Hope that makes sense. I just wanted 1 function this could be called from. Instead of having to duplicate the code.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here how you get all the rows and run your sub on all the rows.

```
Sub sendEmailFromAllRows()
    'Getting the last used row
    With Sheets("YourSheetName")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If
    End With

    'Calling your sub to send the mail for each row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        SendEmail (i)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub SendEmail(iRow As Integer)
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        objEmail.Subject = Cells(iRow, 1).Text
        objEmail.Body = "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(iRow, 3).Text & vbNewLine & "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(iRow, 6).Text
        objEmail.To = Cells(iRow, 5).Text
        objEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "test@test.com"
    objEmail.Display
    objEmail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: I want the code to work out the row from a link at the end of the Row. The Link will say send email. If the user presses this link then it will select the row the link is on and send the email. Hope that makes sense. I just wanted 1 function this could be called from. Instead of having to duplicate the code.. Any ideas?

Comment: So, you want to put the button to send the email in all more than 500 rows?

Comment: No, it will be a link at the end of each row that calls this code but only pulls the data through from that row. So it somehow can Identify that I am on that row and uses the code. Any ideas?

Comment: So the code above calls each row but I dont want it to do that, just call the row the link is on (will be at the end of each row) and it only creates the email from the row you have pressed the link on.